# KSQL query to display receiver and sender info

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I have a table called  `users`  which looks like this:

```
 +----+----------------+
 | id | name           | 
 +----+----------------+
 |  1 | Blake          | 
 |  2 | Jenn           | 
 +----+----------------+
```

And i have a STREAM called  `transactions`  which looks like this:

```
 +----+----------------+----------------+
 | id | sender         | receiver       | 
 +----+----------------+----------------+
 |  1 | 1              | 2              |
 |  2 | 2              | 1              |
 +----+----------------+----------------+
```

So basicly what i want to end up with, looks kind of like this:

```
 +----+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
 | id | sender         | sender_name    | receiver       |receiver_name  |
 +----+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
 |  1 | 1              | Blake          | 2              | Jenn           |
 |  2 | 2              | Jenn           | 1              | Blake          |
 +----+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
```

I've only managed to join the stream and the table partitioned by sender or either receiver, therefore i can only get either the sender info or the receiver info.

Answer (score 0):

You can use two times JOIN with the `users` table to get the expected result:

```
SELECT TR.id, TR.sender, SE.name AS sender_name, TR.receiver, RE.name AS receiver_name
FROM transactions TR
JOIN users SE ON SE.id = TR.sender
JOIN users RE ON RE.id = TR.receiver
```

Answer (score 0):

the point is to create a stream to display that, i've tried that method you described actually but i think it does not work on ksql as it expects a ';' after the first inner join.

```
Statement: create stream  userstransactionsjoinedfinal as select t.txid,t.sender,    
up1.firstname as senderfirstname,up1.lastname as senderlastname,up1.phonenumber as 
senderphonenumber,up1.email as senderemail,t.receiver,up2.firstname as 
receiverfirstname,up2.lastname as receiverlastname,up2.phonenumber as 
receiverphonenumber,up2.email as receiveremail,  t.SENDERWALLETID,  
t.RECEIVERWALLETID,t.status,t.type,t.amount,t.totalfee from transactionsrekeyed 
inner join usersnow up1 on up1.id=t.sender inner join usersnow up2 on up2.id = 
t.receiver;
Caused by: line 1:483: mismatched input 'inner' expecting ';'
Caused by: org.antlr.v4.runtime.InputMismatchException
```